# spyder and anaconda navigator loading problem

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, pyside

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Naveen\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Naveen\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 200, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow   File "C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 53, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()   File "C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 41, in check_qt
    import qtpy   File "C:\Users\Naveen\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found') qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error looks like you are missing the pyside module. Can you run

```
conda install PySide
```

or

```
pip install PySide
```

and see if this fixed that error?